# Create GCD queue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I get an crash when creating a GCD queue in Swift, any idea?

```
var q: dispatch_queue_t?
q = dispatch_queue_create("com.kukodajanos.queryPlaces", 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at the documentational comments for it by alt + click you can see:

[image]

In the attr you can pass 3 things: `nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL and DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` not an Int.

Comment: so bad, compiler does not even see the diff between 0 and nil which causes crash in runtime.

Comment: @Andy What do you mean? 0 does not equal nil so of course it would crash.

Comment: there is no compilation error. you can compile it with 0 and get crash in runtime.

Comment: @Andy Thats true, misread your comment x) It does take a dispatch_queue_attr_t which is an NSObject, so maybe it thinks NSObject can be an Int :D

Answer (score 5):

Pass nil instead of 0:

```
    var q: dispatch_queue_t?
    q = dispatch_queue_create("com.kukodajanos.queryPlaces", nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the 2nd parameter is a reference and not an integer, so you should pass `nil` and not `0`.

Is there any reason why you are declaring the variable as optional? If you are going to assign it next line, then it's better to make it non optional. Also, I guess that you won't change it during its lifetime, so it's probably better to make it immutable:

```
let q = dispatch_queue_create("com.kukodajanos.queryPlaces", nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing nil instead of 0 as dispatch_queue_attr_t shoild do the trick. Also, the function returns an implicitly unwrapped optional, not an optional, is that on purpose?